# TK text widget index not properly counting lines?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried the code below and used the index method to try to get the number of lines of text contained within the text box but i keep getting 1 line returned instead of the 2 that are present in my text box.

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

text = Text(master,width=40,height=50,wrap='word')
text.insert('1.0', 'Here is my text to insert, next i want to test the word wrap')
text.tag_add('font', '1.0', 'end')
text.tag_configure('font', font='arial 12', relief='raised')
text.pack()
print int(text.index('end-1c').split('.')[0])

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

It only counts physical lines, not lines that have wrapped. You've only inserted one line, so it's only counting one line. Wrapping has no effect on the number of lines.